# Pyspark dataframe collecting top records

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a large(50M records) Pyspark dataframe like this.

Book column has names of books and Owner column has the name of owners of the book. Count indicates the number of copies of each book in the respective owners. There could be some copies of the book which are owned by no one, this is indicated by "owner" = None.

I want to do this : For every book, find the top 10 owners and respective counts, ignoring the Nulls.

| book | owner | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| book1 | A | 100 |
| book1 | B | 200 |
| book1 | None | 10 |
| book2 | A | 5 |
| book2 | C | 50 |

This is the code I wrote:

```
  window4=Window.partitionBy('book','owner').orderBy(desc('count'))

   df = df.withColumn('top_owners_details', F.when(F.col(OWNER).isNotNull(), F.struct(
             F.collect_list(OWNER).over(window4).alias('top_owners'),
        F.collect_list('COUNT').over(window4).alias('top_counts')))).otherwise(F.lit(None)))
```

This gives me inconsistent results, top_counts has the count of Nulls included.

I did the same task removing Null rows, but in the downstream activities this is not possible.

What's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the rows having null in owner then rank the counts per book in descending order, then filter the rows where rank is less than 10

```
W = Window.partitionBy('book').orderBy(F.desc('count'))
df1 = (
    df
    .filter(F.col('owner').isNotNull())
    .select('*', F.dense_rank().over(W).alias('rank'))
    .filter('rank <= 10')
)

df1.show()
+-----+-----+-----+----+
| book|owner|count|rank|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|book1|    B|  200|   1|
|book1|    A|  100|   2|
|book2|    C|   50|   1|
|book2|    A|    5|   2|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

Now, if you want to further aggregate the result as struct you can use

```
df2 = df1.groupby('book').agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.struct('owner', 'count')
    ).alias('top_owners')
)

df2.show()
+-----+--------------------+
| book|          top_owners|
+-----+--------------------+
|book1|[{B, 200}, {A, 100}]|
|book2|   [{C, 50}, {A, 5}]|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Comment: FYI - `collect_list` does not ensure an order. using 2 of it might not provide correct result within the `array_zip`.

Comment: Fair enough. Added an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Top Owners") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [("book1", "A", 100),
        ("book1", "B", 200),
        ("book1", None, 10),
        ("book2", "A", 5),
        ("book2", "C", 50)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["book", "owner", "count"])

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('book').orderBy(F.desc('count'))

df = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(windowSpec))

top_10_owners = df.filter((df.owner.isNotNull()) & (df.rank <= 10))

# Collect the details
top_10_owners = top_10_owners.groupBy("book").agg(
    F.collect_list("owner").alias("top_owners"),
    F.collect_list("count").alias("top_counts")
)

top_10_owners.show(truncate=False)
```